# SBS Report displaying critical error events but nothing in Event Viewer

Tags: windows-sbs, eventviewer

We have a Windows Server server set up running SBS 2008 on a 64-bit architecture. When I run my daily SBS Console reports I am being told there is a critical error on the server with Event ID 56 & Source "TermDD". This is all fairly regular behaviour and I have plenty of sites I would normally troubleshoot errors on but the strange thing is there are no errors appearing in the Windows Event Viewer & I can find no help on why this might be... Has anyone experienced this before / know what might be the cause?

Many thanks